# Grails creating list in Index

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

On my index page I want to display all the instances of another class. Shouldn't be hard considering they display all the controllers for you in the gsp in the same manner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
        <title>College Now Portal</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #status {
            background-color: #eee;
            border: .2em solid #fff;
            margin: 2em 2em 1em;
            padding: 1em;
            width: 12em;
            float: left;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1.25em #ccc;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1.25em #ccc;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 1.25em #ccc;
            -moz-border-radius: 0.6em;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0.6em;
            border-radius: 0.6em;
        }

        .ie6 #status {
            display: inline; /* float double margin fix http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html */
        }

        #status ul {
            font-size: 0.9em;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin-bottom: 0.6em;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #status li {
            line-height: 1.3;
        }

        #status h1 {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            margin: 0 0 0.3em;
        }

        #page-body {
            margin: 2em 1em 1.25em 18em;
        }

        h2 {
            margin-top: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 0.3em;
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        p {
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin: 0.25em 0;
        }

        #controller-list ul {
            list-style-position: inside;
        }

        #controller-list li {
            line-height: 1.3;
            list-style-position: inside;
            margin: 0.25em 0;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            #status {
                display: none;
            }

            #page-body {
                margin: 0 1em 1em;
            }

            #page-body h1 {
                margin-top: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN">
    <a href="#page-body" class="skip"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
    <div id="status" role="complementary">
        <h1>Application Status</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>App version: <g:meta name="app.version"/></li>
            <li>Grails version: <g:meta name="app.grails.version"/></li>
            <li>Groovy version: ${GroovySystem.getVersion()}</li>
            <li>JVM version: ${System.getProperty('java.version')}</li>
            <li>Reloading active: ${grails.util.Environment.reloadingAgentEnabled}</li>
            <li>Controllers: ${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.size()}</li>
            <li>Domains: ${grailsApplication.domainClasses.size()}</li>
            <li>Services: ${grailsApplication.serviceClasses.size()}</li>
            <li>Tag Libraries: ${grailsApplication.tagLibClasses.size()}</li>
        </ul>
        <h1>Installed Plugins</h1>
        <ul>
            <g:each var="plugin" in="${applicationContext.getBean('pluginManager').allPlugins}">
                <li>${plugin.name} - ${plugin.version}</li>
            </g:each>
        </ul>
    </div>
</sec:ifAllGranted>
    <div id="page-body" role="main">
        <sec:ifLoggedIn>
                <p>Logged in as ${sec.username()} | <g:link controller='Logout' action=''>logout</g:link></p>
            </sec:ifLoggedIn>
            <sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
                <p>Welcome to College Now Portal, please <g:link controller='Login' action=''>login</g:link></p>
            </sec:ifNotLoggedIn>

        <div id="controller-list" role="navigation">

            <ul>
                <%--
                COMMENTED OUT GSP CONTROLLER LIST
                --%>
                <g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.shortName } }">
                    <li class="controller"><g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.shortName}</g:link></li>
                </g:each>

                <sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_COORDINATOR,ROLE_LIAISON,ROLE_TEACHER">
                <h1>Select a group to manage:</h1>
                    <h1 style="background-color:black; color:white; width:50%">People</h1>

                    <li class="controller"><a href="/collegenowapp/liaison/index">Liaisons</a></li>
                </sec:ifAnyGranted>
                <sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_COORDINATOR">
                    <li class="controller"><a href="/collegenowapp/student/index">Students</a></li>
                </sec:ifAnyGranted>
                <sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_COORDINATOR,ROLE_LIAISON">
                    <li class="controller"><a href="/collegenowapp/teacher/index">Teachers</a></li>
                </sec:ifAnyGranted>

                <sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_COORDINATOR,ROLE_LIAISON,ROLE_TEACHER">
                <h1 style="background-color:black; color:white; width:50%">Items</h1>
                    <li class="controller"><a href="/collegenowapp/book/index">Books</a></li>
                <sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_COORDINATOR,ROLE_LIAISON"> 
                    <li class="controller"><a href="/collegenowapp/course/index">Courses</a></li>
                    <li class="controller"><a href="/collegenowapp/discipline/index">Disciplines</a></li>
                    <li class="controller"><a href="/collegenowapp/school/index">Schools</a></li>
                    <li class="controller"><a href="/collegenowapp/section/index">Sections</a></li>
                </sec:ifAnyGranted>
                </sec:ifAnyGranted>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- SHOWING MEETINGS ON INDEX PAGE-->
            <table>
        <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th><g:message code="meetings.liaison.label" default="Liaison" /></th>

                    <th><g:message code="meetings.place.label" default="Place" /></th>

                    <th><g:message code="meetings.teacher.label" default="Teacher" /></th>

                    <th><g:message code="meetings.time.label" default="Time" /></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${meetingsInstanceList}" var="meetingsInstance">
                <tr>

                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${meetingsInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: meetingsInstance, field: "liaison")}</g:link></td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: meetingsInstance, field: "place")}</td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: meetingsInstance, field: "teacher")}</td>

                    <td><g:formatDate format="MM-dd-yyyy' at 'hh:mm' 'a" date="${meetingsInstance.time}" /></td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="pagination">
                <g:paginate total="${meetingsInstanceCount ?: 0}" />
               </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out how to write queries for the index page. The documentation is very small. Any help from the ground up on queries please. This code almost works. The list I get back returns empty. If I throw a label on it, it says the list is null. It won't read something.

Comment: and what is the error or problem? exceptions? is "Meetings" a domain class or a list? why even reference it again as controller? most likely it is `controller="meetings" action="show" params="${id:it.id}"`

Comment: Meetings is a Domain class. The error is the arguments aren't right or some syntax. I'm just not doing it right. I want to query, but there's no documentation on how to set it up between the gsp and controller.

Comment: then please describe what you ultimate goal here is instead of providing some made up code, that does not work. and for "no docs", please see: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html and http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews

Comment: I wish I could display more relevant information, but this is my best try, sorry I can't write perfect questions because I don't know the answer. My best description was above and says I want to display all instances of a domain class on the index page.......no clue how to do that. That is my ultimate goal and is above. I like those guides though, I'll check them out.There's not very many step by step guides for queries, just the here's how you do it....how I do it where? The controller? the Domain? the console?....

Comment: yes you run your queries in the controller or maybe in a service.  these results build up your model.  the model will be used in the view. handling logic/domain/... in a view is bad practise.

Comment: This is my exact problem. I'm unable to make the queries in a controller and call it in the gsp.

Comment: change ${fieldValue... to <g:fieldValue bean="${meetingsInstance}" field="liaison"/> and try in the gsp use tags. It just do your code more pretty

Comment: Why can't you make the queries in the controller and call the gsp? What's the problem? Also you haven't posted the controller in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by going to **conf** folder in the Grails App. Open the UrlMappings.groovy file.

Now you would see the following line

```
"/"(view:"/index")
```

You would have to change this to point to a certain controller/action

```
"/"(controller:"CustomController", action:"index")
```

In the CustomController, you could reuse the view "/index". Forexample,

```
class CustomController{

    def customService

    def index() {
        def retrievedData = customService.retrieveData(paramsIfNecessary)

        render(view:"/index", model: retrievedData)
    }
    .....
}
```